# Python IDLE from cmd

Tags: python, windows, python-idle

How to open my .py script from anywhere on my pc directly into python idle form command prompt?

Is there any way so that i can type`idle test.py` on cmd so that it opens the test.py file in the current directory and if test.py is not available creates a new file and opens it into idle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a idle.bat file containing

```
@echo off
{Python path}\Lib\idlelib\idle "%cd%\%1"
```

Where {Python path} should be replaced with the directory where python is installed.

**Example**:-

```
@echo off
C:\Python36\Lib\idlelib\idle "%cd%\%1"
```

Copy this idle.bat file into the python directory i.e {Python path} (C:\Python36 in case of the example)

Make sure you've add python path to environment variables

Open cmd in your folder then type

```
idle test.py
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by adding the directory where you have installed the `idle` editor the `PATH` environment variable.

How to do that depends on your operating system: just search the Internet for `add directory to path` plus your operating system: e.g. Windows/Ubuntu, etc.

After changing the environment variable it may be a good idea to restart your PC (to make sure that all programs use the updated version)

Answer (score 3):

You can right click on the idle then you will can see location of it in the properties tab

Navigate to that location and call as below

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 2.7>"IDLE (Python GUI).lnk" C:\Python27\projects\ping.py
```